# Uses of analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

So I understand what an analytic continuation is. However, I have yet to actually use it for anything (other than Borel-Laplace summation which I don't fully understand the use of but that is probably for another MSE question). Its nice that functions sometimes can be analytically continued (the same way that its nice a divergent sum can sometimes be 'summed'), but why would I ever want to analytically continue a function?

Comment: In a loose sense a derivative tells you how a function changes from one point to the next, and accordingly it's definition as a limit quotient has a $z+\Delta z$ and $z$. Of coarse delta z approaches zero so it takes more than just Euler's method a few times to extend a function a finite range out of it's domain but that's why you take the limit as this process goes to infinity, or use a Taylor series, or something else, to do this. As a consequence, values of a function given by analytic continuation are extraordinarily natural. For example, $2^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt(2)$ because $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$,

Comment: a property that also helps you take the derivative of ${2^x}$. Furthermore analytic continuation gives you a uniform representation of the function so things like $sin(x+y)=sin(x)cos(y)-cos(x)sin(y)$ stills works for complex numbers and etc. Anyways, I'm not confident enough to word this into an answer and I know this was asked like 5 years ago, but as a pointer to any one else reading maybe this is helpful. :)

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn 3 years and a quarter ago (we're not that old yet!) I think one thing I have learned since asking the question is that there are genuine situations (ask a physicist) where the function of interest is a priori defined on some part of $\mathbb C$, and it is some sort of mess that isn't easy to handle, e.g. a convolution integral. If by some miracle you can understand the problem "well enough" on the real line and the function is analytic, then analytic continuation gives you the result on the component containing $\mathbb R$ for "free"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you asked, I recently posted a question that would be one of the applications of a.c.

[Analytical continuation of moment generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519607/analytical-continuation-of-moment-generating-function)

Comment: I don't follow. Sure, you can analytically continue your $M(·)$. What for, and so what?

Comment: In this specific case you prove that uniqueness of moment generation functions (when they exist) imply uniqueness of characteristic functions (which always exist) as M(ix) = C(x)

Comment: I actually just understood this! thanks